# Android studio 4.2 Gradle sync failed

Tags: android-studio

My Android Studio has updated to version 4.2 stable, but gradle sync failed.

On my MacBook, the error message is

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No .git directory found!
```

But ".git" directory exists and "git status" works well in terminal.

On my PC, the error message is

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.RefNotFoundException: Ref HEAD cannot be resolved
```

I use git to define version code and version name and it worked well in previous versions.

```
def git = org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.open()
versionName = "${git.describe(tags: true)}"
versionCode = git.tag.list().size()
```

How to solve this problem and build my project?

Comment: Is this an Android application module or a library module?

Comment: @ZsoltBoldizsár It's an application and the code is in build.gradle of root project.

Comment: I know this is deviating away from your question, but the top level build.gradle file shouldn't contain app specific information. It's rather used to declare information that's common to all modules in your project.

Comment: Here's why I asked what kind of module do you have: "In a future version of Android Gradle plugin, the versionName and versionCode properties will also be removed from the DSL for libraries. Currently, there is no way to automatically access the app version code/name from a library sub-project."  https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#version_properties_removed_from_buildconfig_class_in_library_projects

Comment: @ZsoltBoldizsár Thanks for your suggestion. My project has multiple applications for different platforms, and all of them use the same version name, so I declare it in root project.